# Preventing SQL injection without using prepared statements

Tags: php, object-oriented, mysqli

I'm learning OOP and totally new to this way of coding. I've always scripted PHP the procedurial way. Now I've written a working class, which creates a database connection and has the method to create a query which is impossible to SQL-inject by hexing the non-integer data. (I know how to use prepared statements, but i just don't want to use them because there is a slight performance penalty in my case)

**Note:** When hexing data the right way, its not possible to inject.
Have a look at [Zaffy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

**My questions:**

1. What could I've done better?
2. Is it 'wrong' to use this class because its not good OOP (besides its function), or does it not really matter, because it works as how i want it to work? (nobody else is going to maintain the script)

And I must say, I've read multiple tutorials, but it's really difficult to fully understand howto write OOP style if you've never done before!

**databaseconnection.class.php**

```
<?php
class DatabaseConnection {
    private $data, $sql, $conn, $host, $user, $pass, $dtbs;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $dtbs) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->dtbs = $dtbs;

        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dtbs);
        if ($this->conn) {
            return $this->conn;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function query($sql, $data) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->sql = $sql;
        foreach ($data as $val) {
            if (strpos($this->sql, "'%i'") !== false || strpos($this->sql, "'%s'") !== false || strpos($this->sql, '"%i"') !== false || strpos($this->sql, '"%i"') !== false) {
                echo "SQL incorrect: There can't be any quotes around the parameters, because this function does that automaticly for you";
                exit();
            }
            $pos = strpos($this->sql, '%');
            $type = substr($this->sql, $pos, 2);
            if ($type == '%i') {
                if (is_int($val)) {
                    $this->sql = substr_replace($this->sql, $val, $pos, 2);
                } else {
                    echo "Parameter incorrect: Data is not an integer value";
                    exit();
                }
            } elseif ($type == '%s') {
                if (!is_int($val)) {
                    $this->sql = substr_replace($this->sql, "UNHEX('".bin2hex($val)."')", $pos, 2);
                } else {
                    echo "Parameter incorrect: Data is an integer value";
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Parameter incorrect: Parameter %i for integer of %s for all other types of data";
                exit();
            }
        }

        $this->query = $this->conn->query($this->sql);
        return $this->query;

    }

    public function fetch($query) {
        return $query->fetch_assoc();
    }

    public function num_rows($query) {
        return $query->num_rows;
    }

}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
function __autoload($class){
  require('classes/' . strtolower($class) . '.class.php');
}
require('config.php');

$sql = new DatabaseConnection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DTBS);
// The DB_xxxx constants are defined in config.php
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>OOP - Object Orientated Programming</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$data = array(1, "Brian o'Reilly");
$query = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = %i AND name = %s", $data);
if ($sql->num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while ($r = $sql->fetch($query)) {
        echo '<p>User ' . $r['name'] . ' has ID ' . $r['id'] . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>No results</p>";   
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your title to tell us *what your script is doing* - as it stands this title is pretty much applicable to every single question on this site.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for your feedback, will do it right away. I am new on codereview

Comment: It's a nice question you've got here, but be prepared for answers that tell you to use prepared statements.

Comment: `I know how to use prepared statements, but i just don't want to use them because there is a slight performance penalty in my case`. Did you measure it? Care to show your performance difference? Is it a bottleneck?

Comment: `it's really difficult to fully understand howto write OOP style if you've never done before`. I suggest you create a small app (or two) using an OOP framework like Symfony, while adhering to best practices there. It should give you a good introduction to (how they) structure OOP code.

Comment: @Bruno Costa Well, it are the words of someone else, who was facing the issue when executing a query just once per process. Beside that, i just find it very easy to use this class rather then prepared statements. Also this also requires less code (besides the class itself ) . And this class is absolutely secure (really all types of sql injections are blocked here). For the real difference in terms of speed  we should do a side by side comparison.

Comment: bump? :-) Someone who has an answer (1 of) my questions?

Comment: It's just amazing how many people has been deceived by that "zaffy's answer".

Comment: Tell me, whats wrong about it (p.s. i saw your discussion on stackoverflow w/ zaffy, and he had really good arguments)

Comment: The idea that this ugly hexing is somewhat better than regular string formatting.

Comment: Well, both hexing and prepared statements have there cons en pros. Hexing has better performance on single queries, but is less beautiful and you need to write code with caution (but thats always the case, right ?) and prepared statements are easier in error handling (bacause the preparing offcourse), more beautifull and for multiple queries there is a performance boost. Both ways are secure

Comment: If the only performance gain you can get is changing prepared statemens to that hex bullcrap, adding a server will be the better option. Micro optimisations like this will only leed to errors and slower code as the application grows. As others pointed out, to learn you should probably stick to a framework like Laravel or Symfony.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- never `return` from constructor
- avoid having `new` statements in the constructor
- on error, throw an exception instead of `echo` + `exit`
- `%` is used in MySQL's [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) syntax
- you should refactor your `DatabaseConnection::query()` method - it's too high cyclomatic complexity
- constants are global immutable state (it's not as bad as mutable globals, but still a bad idea)
- you should be using [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead of the archaic `__autoload`
- you are mixing HTML with logic .. bad idea, [try this](http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) approach instead
- don't use ".class.php" in filenames, because then you will be screwed, when you start adding interfaces (which one would want to autoload too)

Comment: `% is used in MySQL's LIKE syntax`, You're absolutely right, forgot about that one. Ill just replace it with a question mark (as used in prepared statements also :P:P)